# Question on antecedent phrase and Secondary Dominant Chord

Tags: chords, chord-theory, composition, chord-progressions

I am interested in the discussion entitled "Proper Uses of Minor Seventh Chords" in this question [proper uses of minor seventh chords](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29657/proper-uses-of-minor-seventh-chords). Chord I7 is "secondary dominant" meaning that it has dominant function in any other chord that not the tonic in the song (SimplifyingTheory.Com). My question is: Can I apply this type of chord at the end of an antecedent phrase instead of "dominant" one?
Here are the melodic details!
[image]

Comment: I don't see any logical connection between the linked question and your question. Please edit your question to explain how you think they're related.

Comment: Why are you specifically interested in the I7 chord as opposed to some other secondary dominant?

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies. Truly speaking, I am analyzing my own song now for my report writing. I wish I could attach the song images here (but I don't know how). In the Chorus section, in the key of F Major, the progression is: Bb - C - F - Dm - Gm - C/G - F - F7 (antecedent phrase); Bb - C - F - Dm - Gm - C/G - F - F (consequent phrase). Theoretically, I have to use dominant chord (C Major) at the end of the antecedent phrase. But in fact, I use secondary dominant one (F7). Well, I guess the sound a little bit 'floats' compared to C Major.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question also mentions minor seventh chords, I wonder if what you are really asking is:

> In a minor key, does the chord `i7` have to function as a secondary dominant, or can I simply resolve on it? How about `I7`?

If so, the answer to the first question is **yes, it's common to embellish the minor `i` chord** in jazz and popular music. If you play the sequence of chords `Am C F E7 Am7`, the final `Am7` should feel like home, and removing the seventh to make it an `Am` triad makes it somewhat more stable but doesn't change its functional essence.

`i7` also sounds nice as a transition between the `i` chord and the `iv` chord. However, in this case we can't (strictly speaking) call it a secondary dominant because it isn't a dominant chord. This is where your `I7` comes in: You might have learned that in a major key, the chord `I7` often functions as the secondary dominant of `IV`. (In this case, many analysts would prefer to write `I7` as `V7/IV`, read "five seven of four," to indicate its function.)

Similarly, in a minor key the "four" chord is minor `iv`, and its secondary dominant would be `V7/iv`, which is equivalent to `I7`. *This* chord, which differs from `i7` in that it has a major triad and minor seventh (as opposed to `i7`'s minor triad with minor seventh), is less stable than `i7` and really "wants" to resolve to `iv`.

So, while no rule is set in stone, **the chord `I7` *usually* functions as a secondary dominant** rather than a landing point.

Returning to the key of A minor, you could plausibly end on the chord `Am7`, but the chord `A7` would more likely appear in the middle of a phrase or at the end of a section as a way of transitioning to the chord `Dm` or modulating to the key of D minor. An example of a chord cycle that using `A7` as a secondary dominant could be `|: Am A7 Dm E7 :|`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It's an older resource, but my *[Goetschius, Homophonic Forms](https://imslp.org/wiki/The_Homophonic_Forms_of_Musical_Composition_(Goetschius%2C_Percy))* describes it with a negative statement. In essence...

> The antecedent ends with a... *not* perfect cadence...

According to his definition it could end on a tonic chord of the opening key so long as the cadence is *imperfect*, like a melody pausing on MI instead of DO. He then goes on to describe typical chords to end the antecedent, typically some kind of dominant chord or a dominant or tonic in some new key after a modulation.

So, the broad concept is: the antecedent sets up an expectation for a continuation, because its cadence feels incomplete. The feel of the complete, final cadence only comes with a perfect cadence in the opening key.

---

About your "antecedent" ending on `I7`.

Firstly, let's put that into Roman numeral analysis, because we really need to see what are tonic and dominant.

Antecedent: `F: IV V I , vi ii V64 I (V7/IV)`

Consequent: `F: IV V I , vi ii V64 I I`

You have four iterations of an approach to the tonic `I`.

Whether the phrases is an antecedent will depend a lot on the melody around `Gm C/G F F7`. If the melody goes to `F` at the `F` chord, you really have some kind of perfect cadence type harmony. Categorically, this wouldn't be an antecedent if the melody rests on `F` (solfege DO.)

(Technically `V64 I` isn't a perfect cadence, because of the bass, but in the matter of antecedent phrases, that seems much less important than whether the melody goes to the tonic - solfege DO.)

The `F7` which I labelled `F: V7/IV` importantly comes *after arriving at the tonic chord `I`*. I didn't label it as `Bb: V`, because nothing really establishes the key `Bb`. That `F7` doesn't have the harmonic feel of rest, it feels strongly as *moving* to the subdominant `IV`, the `Bb` chord. If a chord creates a feeling of movement, surely it isn't functioning cadentially.

None of this means there is a problem.

It's only a concern about using the right technical description.

This particular harmonic outline isn't enough to know whether it's an antecedent. We need the melodic details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

And that's not a 'there's no rules, you can do ANYTHING!' answer.  You can do it well within the context of simple, functional harmony.

Here's three simple pairs of phrases.  An antecedent phrase and a consequent phrase if you like to label them that way.

The first is a simple trip from C to G7 and back home again.

The second ventures as far as D7, the dominant of the dominant or 'secondary dominant'.  (Notice I've also thrown in another secondary dominant - the dominant of the dominant of the dominant.)   C, A7, D7.   Then G7 and home.

The third uses  minor seventh chords for the secondary dominants.  Am7 and Dm7.  Then G7, C as before.  We could argue over whether the m7 chords can be strictly labelled as secondary DOMINANTS.  But they're certainly doing what secondary dominants DO!

[image]

Comment: A lot of folk would argue that secondary dominants are only major based. (As in your example 2). I feel a question coming on!

Comment: I'm guessing it's the M3 in a secodary dominant that is also the leading note for the chord it *should* lead to. But it doesn't have to, so does that negate the argument?

Comment: The question asks specifically about the I7 chord (although it's not clear why).

Comment: It can be read as asking specifically about secondary dominants, with I7 as an example.   Anyway, slavish conformity to the terms of a question can be unhelpful.  Sometimes you've got to fix the question before attempting an answer.

Comment: Yeah, the OP seems to think the antecedent needs to end on a dominant, but that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

The way I always thought about secondary dominants is that you can put them before any chord. Got an F? chuck in C7 before it. A C#? go for a G#7. If you are landing on a minor chord, say Bm, just make the secondary dominant an F#7b9 and you are good to go! Of course, this is just a rough sketch, and I am a jazz player by trade, but after years of playing jazz standards, adding in secondary dominants on any chord you like makes things fresh and interesting. Don't even get me started on secondary dominant tritone substitutions!!!

Have fun, that's the main thing. None of this is set in stone.